# Convert type Token to type char?

Tags: c++, algorithm, types, casting, char

I have a Algo that is trying to call a Precedence function in order to compare if one operator has higher priority over the other. I have an error saying I cannot convert type Token to char, I was wondering how I would go about doing so.

```
enter code here
int precedence(char op)
{
if (op == '*' || op == '/') return 0;
return 1;
}

bool comparePrecedence(char a, char b)
{
return precedence(a) < precedence(b);
}

double eval_infix_expr(vector<Token> ie, map<string,double> sym_tab)
{

vector<Token> postfix_expr;
vector<Token> tok_list;
vector<Token> t1;
stack <Token> stack;

while(!(ie.empty())){

    for(size_t i = 0; i < ie.size() ; i++){
            Token tok = ie[i];

    if(!(tok.type == OPERATOR)){
            postfix_expr.push_back(tok);
    }else if(tok.type == OPERATOR){
            while(precedence(tok)){}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the definition of `Token` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a couple different ways:

**Explicit Cast Operator**

In class `Token`, you would need to define a cast operator:

```
class Token
{
public:
    // rest of declaration

    operator char() { return type; } // return whatever char value makes sense
};
```

Then when you call `while (precedence(tok)) {}`, it will be able to cast it implicitly.

Alternatively,

**Accessor**

Instead of relying on a cast, you can declare an accessor and actually use the accessor:

```
class Token
{
public:
    // rest of declaration

    char GetType() const { return type; } // or whatever makes sense for your token class
};
```

Then when you call `while (precedence(tok.GetType())) {}` (note the difference in the access), it will know what you are doing.

SIDE NOTE:

The follow block of code is not really necessary:

```
if(!(tok.type == OPERATOR)) // if Not operator
{
    postfix_expr.push_back(tok);
}
else if(tok.type == OPERATOR) // else if operator
{
    while(precedence(tok)){}
}
```

Avoiding the potential infinite loop, the conditionals can be written as

```
if (tok.type == OPERATOR) // if operator
{
    while(precedence(tok)){} // NOTE:  This will either be a noop, or an infinite loop ... never anything useful!
}
else // otherwise
{
    postfix_expr.push_back(tok);
}
```

Making it more readable.

Comment: I think (we don't see it though) Token has got a member that is of type `char`

Comment: He would just use whatever member is of type `char` as the return value for either the accessor or the cast operator.

Comment: ok, but maybe his problem is not the cast, but he is using the wrong member.

Comment: In the code he posted, he wasn't using a cast nor an accessor.  He was simply passing in the instance of `Token` (`tok`).  He as several problems with the code overall, but to answer his question, he has to provide access to the member (and both methods I displayed would accomplish that task ... his other problems are outside the scope of the original question).

Answer (score 0):

In this line : `while(precedence(tok)){}`, you're calling the function `precedence` which take in argument a `char` but you're passing the variable `tok` which is a `Token`

The two types cannot be converted.

My crystal ball says that with `while(precedence(tok.type)){}`, the program *may* compile but this line makes no sense ! At best, it's useless, at worst, it's an infinite loop.